# Return XML using SQL query

Tags: sql, xml, group-by

I have a table as below

| ID | Test |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa |
| 2 | bbbb |
| 3 | cccc |

With a SQL query for XML as below I 'm receiving as output that follows

```
SELECT Id, test 
      from table_1 for xml PATH('Person')
```

I receive an output as below

```
<Person>
 <Id>1<\ID>
 <test>aaaa<\test>
<\Person>
<Person>
 <Id>1<\ID>
 <test>bbbb<\test>
<\Person>
<Person>
 <Id>1<\ID>
 <test>cccc<\test>
<\Person>
```

But I want a output as below, which could take 1 ID and all the tests in one tag

```
<Person>
 <Id>1<\ID>
 <tests>
  <test>aaaa<\test>
  <test>bbbb<\test>
  <test>cccc<\test>
<\tests>
<\Person>
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL sort of grouping but not exactly

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Test VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, Test) VALUES
(1, 'aaaa'),
(2, 'bbbb'),
(3, 'cccc');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT TOP(1) ID
    , (
    SELECT Test AS [test]
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('tests')
) 
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY id ASC
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Person');
```

**Output**

```
<Person>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <tests>
    <test>aaaa</test>
    <test>bbbb</test>
    <test>cccc</test>
  </tests>
</Person>
```